# Is it possible to run/debug a bios rom file in an emulator, And if so how?

Tags: reverse-engineering, bios, emulation

What I am trying todo is find a way to observe the execution flow of the BIOS rom file without having to flash it to the motherboard because I don't know of a way to debug or step through it during the bootup process.

The motherboard in question is a P6T7 WS Supercomputer as seen [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6T7_WS_SuperComputer/).

[This](https://336ed26ec2fe3b0db85eeb53654b8d61385e2817.googledrive.com/host/0B4YPWGzx_WjeS0R1bTZ1RUNoZG8/) directory contains my research into the bios itself. It has rom files both downloaded from Asus's website above and ripped from my motherboard. The bin files came from the mmtool and the report.txt is a cpu-z report file with personally identifying information removed.

I want to learn how it runs so i can possibly write my own OROM file and or add UEFI support to the BIOS. This is a legacy bios which asus seems to have stopped supporting so no more updates will come out for it.

I have radare2 and ida pro available however I dont know how to use them on the bios rom file since it seems to contain this

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
----------------------------------------

73152         0x11DC0         Microsoft executable, portable (PE)
224736        0x36DE0         Microsoft executable, portable (PE)
717691        0xAF37B         CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
1842624       0x1C1DC0        Microsoft executable, portable (PE)
1994208       0x1E6DE0        Microsoft executable, portable (PE)
```

output is from binwalk.

Comment: "add UEFI support to the BIOS" are you sure upgrading the motherboard is not the less painful way?

Comment: @Dani I plan to in the future once i find a motherboard like this one but more recent because it runs like a dream for being kinda old. However for now i wanna see if i can do my own updates.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to load/test/debug intel UEFI image/BIOS @JfmMeyers ?